# Inject dependency from parent controller

Tags: angularjs

We are using `$routeProvider` to inject some dependencies to the routing configuration. Something like this:

```
.when("/some/url", { 
    templateUrl: "/some/html",
    controller: "someController",
    controllerAs: "vm", 
    resolve: {
        __variable: ["someServiceDependency", function (someServiceDependency) {
            return someServiceDependency.someCall();
        }]
    }
})
```

that way we inject __variable to our controller:

```
angular
    .module("someModule")
    .controller("someController", someController);

someController.$inject = [
    "$scope",
    ...
    "__variable"];

function someController(
    $scope,
    ...
    __variable) {
    ... here we do something with __variable
}
```

The problem we have now is that this `someController` is rendered via routing, but also is used as a nested controller from other controllers

```
<div>
  ....some html rendered via ng-route.....
  <div ng-controller="someController">
    ... specific data from someController
  </div>
</div>
```

thus, when rendering the nested controller, angular cannot find the __variableProvider, as it does not exist.

One option is to declare all this dependencies as providers, instead of setting them in the `resolve` section, but finally that approach will create tens of providers, and we prefer to keep the control in one part.

Is it possible to "inject" via ng-init, or inject if the provider exists, or fill with empty if not exists? that way we can do something like:

```
<div>
  ....some html rendered via ng-route.....
  <div ng-controller="someController" ng-init="initVariable(__variable)">
    ... specific data from someController
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: ng-init is generally antipattern. You can expose it to scope in someController with `$scope.__variable = __variable`. It will be available in directives with inherited scope (such as ng-controller).

Comment: that will work for the second case (as sub controller), but will fail when rendered via ng-route

Comment: You can't use someController like regular controller because of that, unless you provide default service value like `app.value('__variable', null)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$injector` service to get dependency if it's present like:

```
var servicePresent = $injector.has('testService');

if (servicePresent) {
   testService = $injector.get('testService');
   $scope.response = testService.testFn();
}
```

Here is the working example:
https://plnkr.co/edit/tUT1y9s5xvofLlAkAIT0?p=preview